# Sum and Group By in Linq to SQL?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

Just getting started with Linq to SQL so forgive the newbie question. I'm trying to reproduce the following (working) query in Linq to SQL (VB.NET):

```
Select
    f.Title,
    TotalArea = Sum(c.Area)
From Firms f
Left Join Concessions c on c.FirmID = f.FirmID
Group By f.Title
Order by Sum(c.Area) DESC
```

(A Firm has many Concessions; a Concession has an area in hectares. I want a list of Firms starting with the ones that have the greatest total area of all their concessions.)

I'm imagining something like this as the Linq to SQL equivalent (**pseudo-code**)

```
From f As Firm In Db.Firms _
Order By f.Concessions.Sum(Area)
```

... but that's not right. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I usually don't post meta comments, but 29k views and 7 upvotes? That is sad

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Answer

Here's the correct Linq to SQL equivalent

```
From c In Concessions _
Join f In Firms on f.FirmID equals c.FirmID _
Group by f.Title _
Into TotalArea = sum(c.OfficialArea)  _
Order by TotalArea Descending _
Select Title, TotalArea
```

Thanks to @CMS for pointing me to [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) - what a great tool. You just point it to your database and you're off and running. Not only are hundreds of samples included, but you can run them against included live databases. I was able to arrive at the above query in just a few minutes starting from the provided samples.

Comment: Can you provide the C# version of this segment?  I've tried but not successful.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737922.aspx) you can find many examples about using aggregate functions and grouping, additionally I recommend you very much [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), it's a great tool to test your queries on the fly and it's very good way to learn LINQ, it comes preloaded with 200 examples.