# Linq To SQL Group By and Sum

Tags: linq-to-sql

Her is an image showing a the table i have, b the grid i need to display.
opps cant post image. ill try to explain. My table have four colums.

1. Project Number(String)
2. ItemNumber(String)
3. Location(String)
4. Qty.(Real).

My grid need to look like this.

1. ProjectNumber
2. ItemNumber
3. QtyMain.
4. QtyOther.

I Need to write a linq query Grouping evry line so i will se 1 Line pr Project/ItemNumber combination summing qty into 2 differetn colums 1 showing to qty where location is main and 1 showing the qty where location is not (!=) main. Can linq do this for me, or how can thsi be done?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Sum and Group By in Linq to SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216513/sum-and-group-by-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: I cant se that it is, but maybe it just because i dont know VB that well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public class Foo
{
    public Int32 ProjectNumber;
    public String ItemNumber;
    public String InventLocation;
    public Int32 Qty;
}

void Main()
{
    List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>(new[]{
        new Foo { ProjectNumber = 1, ItemNumber = "a", InventLocation = "Main", Qty = 3 },
        new Foo { ProjectNumber = 1, ItemNumber = "a", InventLocation = "Main", Qty = 3 },
        new Foo { ProjectNumber = 1, ItemNumber = "a", InventLocation = "Sub", Qty = 2 },
        new Foo { ProjectNumber = 1, ItemNumber = "a", InventLocation = "Sub", Qty = 1 },
        new Foo { ProjectNumber = 1, ItemNumber = "a", InventLocation = "Sub2", Qty = 5 }
    });

    var foo = from f in foos
              group f by new { f.ProjectNumber, f.ItemNumber } into fGroup
              select new {
                ProjectNumber = fGroup.Key.ProjectNumber,
                ItemNumber = fGroup.Key.ItemNumber,
                QtyMain = fGroup.Where (g => g.InventLocation == "Main").Sum (g => g.Qty),
                Rest = fGroup.Where (g => g.InventLocation != "Main").Sum (g => g.Qty)
              };
    foo.Dump();
}
```

Resulting in:

```
IEnumerable<> (1 item)  
ProjectNumber ItemNumber QtyMain Rest 
1             a          6       8
```

Comment: @Scarface: BTW, I recommend (esp. if you're starting out or just getting the hang of it) looking at LINQpad. The above will copy-paste in that tool and show you how useful it can be (just be sure to select "Language: C# program" above the editor window.

Comment: Ok thx, i have it installed actually, just haven't tried it out yet, im pretty new to Linq :)