# Is it possible to select the sum of a column, grouping by another column?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, sum

Table format:

```
Date   |   NumberIWantToSum   |   ID(PK)   |   ForeignKeyID
```

For a given ForeignKeyID, I want  sum all of the NumberIWantToSum values which have the same date, using Linq2SQL and then populate a list of my own custom class with all of the value from the row.

Is this possible?

So, given the values:

```
    Date   |   NumberIWantToSum   |   ID(PK)   |   ForeignKeyID
   1/1/1             1                  123              2
   1/1/1             12                 124              2
   1/1/1             44                 125              3
   1/1/2             14                 126              2
```

I am given the parameter for ForeignKeyID for this method, let's assume it's 2, so this method should return the rows :

```
   1/1/1             13                 123              2
   1/1/2             14                 126              2
```

My attempt to do this:

```
(from o in context.table.Where(r => r.GroupByThisColID == GroupByThisColID)
 select new CustomClass()
 {
     ID = o.ID,
     Date = o.Date,
     NumberIWantToSum = o.NumberIWantToSum,
     ForeignKeyID  = o.ForeignKeyID
 }).ToList();
```

However, this does not sum the values of NumberIWantToSum and combine them into one row.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: The ID field - it's included in the expected results, but not in the group by (or a MIN/MAX/etc). So how would it know to choose 123 and not 124? Something missing there...?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but shouldn't a group by with 2 yield 1+12+14?

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle this either; it shouldn't matter which is returned for this column (since either would be unique). Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: @JustinPihony - no, since the 44 has a  GroupByThisColID of 3, wheras the rest have 2. I only wish to return the values where  GroupByThisColID is 2 (or whatever the passed in parameter is).

Comment: I'm not an expert on LINQ, but in TSQL your 2 is a WHERE parameter, and the DATE is the Group By column. However, you have to tell it what to do with the ID field, else it will return one row for each unique value here, so that's not going to Sum anything.

Comment: @SimonKiely Oops, now I had the typo...corrected now, but I meant 1+12+14

Comment: @JustinPihony No, I want 2 separate values returned due to the 2 separate dates! Apologies if I was unclear, I think it was due to my incorrect use of Group By which SeanW kindly pointed out. I have updated the question now to fix this (hopefully).

Comment: This question has been asked many times before, on and off SO. What have you tried?

Comment: @Jeff I have searched thorougholy for this question, the added caveat of the ID in the CustomClass makes this a little bit unique. I have tried what is in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum and Group By in Linq to SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216513/sum-and-group-by-in-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your explanation `GroupByThisColdID` is used to filter, not group. You actually want to group by date.

Try this:

```
var query = from o in context.table
            where o.GroupByThisColID == GroupByThisColID
            group o by o.Date into grouping
            select new CustomClass()
            {
                ID = grouping.First().ID,
                Date = grouping.Key,
                SummedNumbers = grouping.Sum(g => g.NumberIWantToSum),
                GroupByThisColID  = grouping.First().GroupByThisColID
            };
```

Using `grouping.First().ID` will return the first ID, although they might be different. This would be "123" in your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

```
var r = from x in table
        group x by x.GroupByThisColID into g
        select new
        {
            Key = g.Key,
            Sum = g.Sum(i => i.NumberIWantToSum)
        };

foreach (var x in r)
{
    var key = x.Key;
    var sum = x.Sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var results = context.table.GroupBy( t=> t.GroupByThisColID)
    .Select( g => new CustomClass()
        {
            GroupByThisColID = g.Key,
            ColumnSum = g.Sum( p => p.NumberIWantToSum)
        });
```