# Return Table or List with Linq Group By

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a typed datatable with the columns month and money. My goal is to get an object that I can bind to a dgv (table or list) where the money is grouped by month.

In SQL I would accomplish this with

```
Select month, sum(money) from table
group by month
```

I tried (according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216513/sum-and-group-by-in-linq-to-sql) )

```
Public Function Get Overview(...)

dim query = 
from dt In _dataset.Table.AsEnumerable() 
Group By dt.Week 
Into Test = Sum(dt.money) 
Select Test

Return Test
End Function
```

I cannot run this but the returntype is `IEnumerable(of Double)` so to me it looks I do not get the Table or List back that I can bind to my dgv. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my query?

Edit:
This is Linq to datasets.

Declaration and instance

```
Privat _dataset as Dataset1
Private _adapter as New Dataset1TableAdapters.Table
_dataset = New Dataset1
_adapter.Fill(_dataset.Table)
```

Comment: Wrap the linq in ().ToList();

Comment: What is this, Linq-To-Sql, Linq-To-Enities, Linq-To-Object, Linq-To-DataSet, ...? What is `dt`?

Comment: Sorry for missing that information. Sometimes when you are a nub you can miss important information. It is Linq to Dataset. I gave you more information above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Select Test` you explicitly select only the aggregated values of the `money` column.

Your query should look like:

```
Dim query = From dt In _dataset.Table.AsEnumerable() 
            Group By week = dt.Week 
            Into result = Sum(dt.money)
```

Note that this yields an `IEnumerable(Of ...)` of an anynomous type. If you want to use the result outside the current method, create a type that represents this result or use e.g. the `Tuple` class, like:

```
Dim query = From dt In _dataset.Table.AsEnumerable() 
            Group By week = dt.Week 
            Into result = Sum(dt.money) 
            Select Tuple.Create(week, result)
```

This yields an `IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of TheTypeOfWeek, TheTypeOfMoney))` which you can bind to your DGV.

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me a lot. Especially that you also helped me with the result conversion!